# Do I need segues when using a UITabBarController?

Tags: ios7, xcode5, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

This is probably a *lame* question, but I don't know the answer (I have looked but found nothing).  I created an iPad app that looks like this:

[image]

The red arrow is pointing to a UITabBarController, from which I connected *segues* to the other UIViewControllers.  I also have a UINavigationController to the right, where I use *segues* to go between each of the modal scenes.

My question is:  do I really need the *segues* that are attached to the UITabBarController?  I have a need to programmatically go to one of the tab views from one of the modal scenes, but I can't seem to give an identity to any of the *segues* emanating from the UITabBarController, which makes me think they are useless/not used.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer is YES, they are needed. https://devforums.apple.com/message/930339#930339